# Save audio in a buffer for later playback

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

With the Web Audio API, I want to save audio in a buffer for later use. I've found some examples of saving audio to disk, but I only want to store it in memory. I tried connecting the output of the last AudioNode in the chain to an AudioBuffer, but it seems AudioBuffer doesn't have a method for accepting inputs.

```
var contextClass = (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);

// Output compressor
var compressor = context.createDynamicsCompressor();
var compressor.connect(context.destination);

var music = context.createBufferSource();
// Load some content into music with XMLHttpRequest...
music.connect(compressor);
music.start(0);

// Set up recording buffer
var recordBuffer = context.createBuffer(2, 10000, 44100);

compressor.connect(recordBuffer); 
// Failed to execute 'connect' on 'AudioNode': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
```

Is there something I can use instead of AudioBuffer to achieve this? Is there a way to do this without saving files to disk?

Answer (score 1):

Well, turns out [Recorder.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) does exactly what I wanted. I thought it was only for exporting to disk, but when I looked closer I realized it can save to buffers too. Hooray!